# Support for multiple languages in NoSQL solution?

Tags: database-design, localization, nosql

We're about to embark on a new project where we will (hopefully) be supporting 1000s of customers and so we're looking into the architecture. One key aspect of the application will be support for multiple languages (English, Spanish etc., no limits on number of languages). We have a lot of experience in modeling this is a traditional RDBMS (Sql Server, Oracle etc.), but we're struggling when it comes to NoSQL 'modelling'. In a SQL model we would create a 'text' table with a 'language' column pointing to a 'language' table with all the different languages in. That way all texts can be represented in all supported languages. Consider a simple example:

table: Category
columns: id (PK), Enabled (Bool)

table: Category_Descriptions
columns: id (PK), CategoryID (FK), LanguageID (FK), Description (Text)

table: Language
columns: id (PK), Enabled (Bool)

table: Language_Descriptions
columns: id (PK), DescriptionLanguageID (FK), LanguageID (FK), Description (Text)

So all languages will be stored in the Language table, with their corresponding description stored in the Language_Descriptions table. Furthermore all categories will be stored in the Category table, with descriptions in all languages in Category_Descriptions table. So to get all categories on a given language (English = 1):

```
select c.id, cd.Description 
from   Category c, Category_Descriptions cd 
where  c.id = cd.CategoryID 
and    c.Enabled = 1;
```

Of course a category isn't very useful by itself; it would be part of another entity, such as an incident report:

table: Incident
columns: id (PK), Created (Date), CategoryID (FK), etc.

To get the information from this table I would then do the same join as before and select the description column on the correct language. Basic stuff, we've all done this before...

Finally we arrive at my question: How the heck do I store this properly in a NoSQL database? :)

I have looked at a couple of (bad) solutions:

1. Store only the code and then lookup the correct description run-time
2. Store the last used description along with the language code and
   then update if language has changed (different user)
3. Store all descriptions in same document
4. Store the description of the code in the active language and then add the description to new languages when needed (ie. when requested in an unused language)

All of these solutions have quite a few drawbacks and requires a lot of work to implement and maintain... So, any input on how to best solve this would be appreciated.

EDIT: We're looking at NoSQL for two reasons:

1. Performance (Scale)
2. Dynamic Schema (need to do a lot of work to make this happen in SQL)

Comment: Is the question unclear/unrealistic/stupid? No responses at all, kind of strange...

Answer (score 3):

It's been a while since this was asked, but I figured why not =) ...

From my experience with NoSQL, you have to first really try to forget your RDMS background and your strong desire to normalize data.  It's ok to have redundant data.  It's ok to store things in large quantities (even if it's redundant!)  It's ok to have data not be consistent.  In other words, since you would store the language description in potentially 5 places ... it's ok to have those 5 places be different for a period of time.

If you're willing to make those concessions in the name of performance and dynamic schema, then that might help you model.

I think a good place to start is by using the UI as the model.  If you were a web developer and wanted this data, what would you need?  Ideally you want to minimize the number of calls the web developer needs to make to get what they need.  That sometimes helps you decide how much information to put inside of a document.

I think you hinted at the ability to run queries across documents with your SQL example.  In other words, if you do your best and create 10 document types, and things are mostly going well, and then you suddenly realize you need to do a "join", you will run into trouble.

NoSQL is not good at doing conceptual joins.

The way most of them go about it is to use map/reduce.  For example, in Mongo, you can write map/reduce functions that will essentially give you the join functionality.  You pay the price in speed however.

But if you're willing to let the complex queries (things that don't fit your original document model) run a bit slower, you can accomplish anything you want.

How would you determine which queries need to be fast and which can be a bit slow?  Again I would point to the UI.

Also simple trial and error with modeling has really helped me.  I realize that's a lame suggestion, but it's true.  =)

Comment: Thank you for you response. I see your point on not being to concerned with normalization; that's fine. But it's quite possible that we will have upwards of a 1000 entities, each with 20 properties  with a description on 4-12 languages... So in Sql we'd have 20*12 descriptions, but in NoSql we'd have 20*12*[thousands]. That's gonna start costing in terms of storage... Not cool! :)

Answer (score 3):

You can make a description field as an array of objects with two fields: locale and text. Just ensure that the first member of this array is always a value in your default locale.

Comment: I like this approach. It's good for searching in the future. Any comments about how to query a documents with projection to desired language? (with fallback to default locale if desired doesn't exist)? I'm trying to use $elemMatch but if there is no object with queried locale MongoDB will not return a field